# Counting nested Navigation table rows with LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, count, sum

I am very new to c# and LINQ, now I need to do some aggregation on the navigation tables nested one after the other, the result was generated as below:

```
[{
    "ForumMain":"General Forum",
    "Forums": [{
            "Title":"My First Forum", 
            "TopicCount":4,
            "PostCount":[2,0,1,0]
        },
        {
            "Title":"My Second Forum",
            "TopicCount":0,
            "PostCount":[]
        }]
}]
```

I wanted `PostCount` also be the sum, but it is giving debug null error when I try to sum `PostCount`, please see my linq query below:

```
var data = ForumCategories.Select(f => new
{
    ForumMain = f.CategoryName,
    Forums = f.Fora.Select(t => new
    {
        Title = t.ForumName,
        TopicCount = t.Topics.Count,
        PostCount = t.Topics
        .Select(m => m.ForumPosts.Count == null ? 0 : m.ForumPosts.Count)
    })
});
```

Comment: want to count the items in PostCount or SUM the items in PostCount. because in your linq query you do a count and not a SUM. m.ForumPosts.Sum()

Comment: yes I should have said the Count, but seeing the outcome result of my postcount, I  said it to sum [2,0,1,0] = 3. Anyway, my problem has been solved. thanks for your input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand what you want under `PostCount` to have the total number of post you have for all the topics in that `Forum`. Right?

If so:

```
var data = db.ForumCategories.Select(f => new
{
    ForumMain = f.CategoryName,
    Forums = f.Fora.Select(t => new
    {
        Title = t.ForumName,
        TopicCount = t.Topics.Count,
        PostCount = t.Topics.SelectMany(x => x.ForumPosts).Count()
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks man. to clarify the sum and count, because when I was getting an array of counts in the postcount so I thought sum would work, but it was throwing error when the the array was empty. Can you please explain the SelectMany scenario here what was happening that the Select didn't work.

Comment: @Khalil - Yes. Under each `Topic` you have many `ForumPosts`. If you just perform a `Count` on the `Topic` you count how many items you have in that collection - but what you want is to know how many items you have all together within all the inner lists. `SelectMany` enables you to iterate a collection and output for each item a collection of items (in this case for each Topic all the posts). Then all these collections are merged (by the `SelectMany`) and that is what you want to count

Comment: @Khalil - look at the [SO Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries#t=20160803064328417214) for `SelectMany`

Comment: Yes, very well done, did what I wanted. I will ready the documentation you provided. It looks like you will welcome me if I ask you more questions in future